# how to fix f-strings breaking backward compatibility python 3.5/3.6+

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, f-string

I have found some code which is apparently designed for python 3.6.

For some reason I need to run that code in a python 3.5 environment.
Supposedly, the two versions should be backward compatible.
However, the original code abuses in f-strings, raising hundreds of errors in py35

do you know any tool to remove those fstrings, or a clean workaround?

Comment: Have you tried any of the "backports"? Like https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings

Comment: that would be ideal. but I can not install packages via pip :(

Comment: the clean workaround is to replace `print(f'{some}breaking{thing}')` by  `print('{}breaking{}'.format(some,thing))` ... because the code you are using is definitly not below 3.6 safe. Luck with fixing it.

Comment: you could maybe write code to modify those code files in one go, and then manually or by running the code check over any mistakes.

Comment: could you upvote the question if you think it might be useful to someone else?I have got a close but honestly I think the queston is legit

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a backward-compatible Python 3.6 piece of software if you're using f-String formatting. The reason for this is that it's a fundamental syntax feature, so "making" it compatible with Python 3.5, for example, would imply changing the Python 3.5 interpreter itself.

The only "clean workaround" I can think of is formatting the strings in a way that does not conflict the previous Python versions you want your software compatible with.

Hope this helps.